# DragPanelExtender not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a simple ASP.NET form that Im using to learn some AJAX controls.

My code is:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
<div>
    <div style="height: 300px; width: 250px; float: left; padding: 5px;">
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="250px">
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Width="40%" Height="20%" BorderWidth="1px"
                BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="black">
                Drag This Panel
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
</div>
<ajaxToolkit:DragPanelExtender ID="Panel1_DragPanelExtender" BehaviorID="DragP1"
    DragHandleID="Panel1" TargetControlID="Panel1" runat="server">
</ajaxToolkit:DragPanelExtender>
</form>
```

My problem is that when I drag the Panel it doesn't stay where I leave it.  It immediately moves back.  shouldn't it stay where I leave it.  I appreciate if I postback it will move back but I'm staying on the page incurring no new events.

Is this right?

Mike

Answer (score 0):

I never used drag panel but I think there is something wrong with your markup.
Both the `DragHandleID` and `TargetControlID` are set to Panel1 which is wrong.

```
DragHandleID="Panel1" TargetControlID="Panel1"
```

According to the example on the Ajax site it's markup is http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/DragPanel/DragPanel.aspx

```
<ajaxToolkit:DragPanelExtender ID="DPE1" runat="server"
TargetControlID="Panel3"
DragHandleID="Panel4" />
```

In the above markup they have used different panels for the targetControlID and DragHandleID 
so you should update your markup as

```
<ajaxToolkit:DragPanelExtender ID="Panel1_DragPanelExtender" BehaviorID="DragP1"
   DragHandleID="Panel1" TargetControlID="Panel2" runat="server">
</ajaxToolkit:DragPanelExtender>
```